# elasticsearch geo bounding box not returning results

Tags: php, elasticsearch, geolocation, elasticsearch-5

I'm trying to use the Geo Bounding Box functionality of elastic search to return results in my box of choice. I get the boundary coordinates from Google Maps, and it's in the NorthEast and SouthWest format.

This is an example dump of the parameters passed to the elasticsearch php client (converted to JSON for readability):

```
{
   "index":"MyIndex",
   "body":{
      "query":{
         "bool":{
            "must":{
               "match_all":{

               }
            },
            "filter":{
               "geo_bounding_box":{
                  "location":{
                     "top_right":{
                        "lat":53.2323104,
                        "lon":6.704821
                     },
                     "bottom_left":{
                        "lat":52.3136724,
                        "lon":4.311799
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Here a few example results that are in ES and I get returned when I do a normal simple search (no geo/bounding box):

```
[
   {
      "object_id":14396,
      "object_type":"POI",
      "location":{
         "lat":53.05194,
         "lon":5.38417
      }
   },
   {
      "object_id":24046,
      "object_type":"POI",
      "location":{
         "lat":52.52711,
         "lon":5.06319
      }
   },
   {
      "object_id":24680,
      "object_type":"POI",
      "location":{
         "lat":52.72525,
         "lon":4.96201
      }
   }
]
```

I believe these should all be returned by the bounding box search, what am I missing here?

Edit: Included mapping below

```
{
   "MyIndex":{
      "mappings":{
         "pois":{
            "properties":{
               "object_id":{
                  "type":"string"
               },
               "object_type":{
                  "type":"string"
               },
               "location":{
                  "type":"geo_point"
               },
            }
         },
      }
   }
}
```

Edit 2: Raw response with data in ES:

```
{
   "_index":"MyIndex",
   "_type":"pois",
   "_id":"14916",
   "_score":1,
   "_source":{
      "object_id":"14916",
      "object_type":"POI",
      "location":{
         "lat":53.13915,
         "lon":6.19422
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you show what you get form `curl -XGET localhost:9200/MyIndex/_mapping`?

Comment: @val updated my answer with the mapping. Please note that the example result is not a raw response from ES. That's the response I get from my API. I've also added the raw ES response now.

Answer (score -1):

The `top_left` and `bottom_right` values are incorrectly passed. Try to the set the values as following:

```
location :{
    "top_right":{
        "lat":53.2323104,
        "lon":4.311799
        },
    "bottom_left":{
        "lat":52.3136724,
        "lon":6.704821
        }
}
```

Comment: You've just copy-paste presented **example dump (converted to JSON for readability)**. You didn't provide an answer. Your "answer" is not an answer.

Comment: @AksenP the point I am trying to make here is the `top_right` and `bottom_left` lat lon values were incorrectly passed. I have corrected them and pasted my request data from kibana dev tools. Let me update my answer with explanation. Thanks for pointing it up. appreciate that!

Comment: **"lon":6.704821** vs. **"lon":4.311799** - useless correction, because these values are dynamic. You didn't get the question as it is.